# Disk management (cleanup) in a stopped docker container

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-container

I'm running an `elasticsearch` docker container on my virtual machine and recently have got an `elasticsearch` failure, container just stopped. The reason - my ssd is out of space.

I can easily cleanup my indexes but the real issue here is that I actually cannot start the docker to do that. Container stops right after start without an ability to go via web UI or bash to cleanup space.

How can I cleanup my disk in a stopped container which I couldn't start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [official `elasticsearch` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/), the Elasticsearch data directory will be a volume (mind the `VOLUME /usr/share/elasticsearch/data` statement in that image's `Dockerfile`).

You can now start another container, mounting your original container's volumes using the `--volumes-from` option to perform whatever cleanup tasks you deem necessary:

```
docker run --rm -it \
    --volumes-from=<original-elasticsearch-container> \
    ubuntu:latest \
    /bin/bash
```

If that should fail, you can also run `docker inspect` on your Elasticsearch container and find the volume's directory in the host filesystem (assuming you're using the default `local` volume driver). Look for a `Mounts` section in the JSON output:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Name": "<volume-id>",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/<volume-id>/_data",
        "Destination": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": ""
    }
],
```

The `"Source"` property will describe the volume's location on your host filesystem. When the container is started, this directory is simply bindmounted into the container's mount namespace; any changes you make in this directory on the host will be reflected in the container when it is started.